# Receiving weird host can't be null error with ef core

Tags: ef-core-3.1

I have recently installed the EF Core 3.1.6 on a home project using postgresql.

I have the connection string, and can add migrations easily with the Package Manager Console. If I run my application the Database.Migrate() will migrate the migrations easily. However if I attempt to update the database via the Package Manager Console with an 'update-database' I receive this error:

```
System.ArgumentException: Host can't be null
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.Open(NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.<>c__DisplayClass32_0.<<Open>g__OpenLong|0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.Open()
   at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Storage.Internal.NpgsqlDatabaseCreator.Exists()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.HistoryRepository.Exists()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabaseImpl(String targetMigration, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
Host can't be null
```

I do not know what is happening, if I am missing a nuget package, etc. Any possible help and explanation for what is happening would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You should set `ConnectionStrings` in program.cs|startup.cs.

Add this into the **program.cs** (.net7)

```
builder.Services.Configure<ConnectionStrings>(
    builder.Configuration.GetSection(nameof(ConnectionStrings))
);
```

or **startup.cs** (.net6):

```
services.Configure<ConnectionStrings>(Configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings"));
```

Answer (score 1):

add bellow lines in Program.cs file

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDBContext>(options =>
options.UseNpgsql(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
builder.Services.AddScoped<IDataAccessProvider, DataAccessProvider>();
```

and bellow connection string in appsettings.json

```
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "User ID=postgres;Password=******;Host=127.0.0.1;Port=****;Database=at;"
  },   "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by putting the --startup-project flag in my migration script like this:

dotnet ef database update --startup-project "startup project path" --project "DbContext path" --verbose

Answer (score 0):

I Solved it. It had to do with the way I was building the connection string on runtime and not buildtime.

Comment: How did you solve it? Did you find a solution on runtime? I am using enviroment variables and have to set them in the powershell to make it work. Somehow it does not tale the default values...

Answer (score 0):

You should export your env variables first from terminal like this:

```
export $(grep -v '^#' ./dev.env | xargs)
```

> {dev.env} -> change it to your env file

Answer (score 0):

Check your connection string in your startup class you may have different connection string name with the config of the database in the startup when you are using appsetting.json

[Startup configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0H1uZ.png)

[appsetting.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVT15.png)

Answer (score 0):

Ok this may sounds stupid. But our team accidentally ignore the relevant appsettings.json file for our contract test.

**CopyToPublishDirectory** was set to **Never**.

Thus the connection string was never set in the first place. When docker runs, the connection string was empty.

[image: appsetting.json was ignored from being published]

Answer (score 0):

I have this code snippet that read env file and set it to process environment variables

```
      using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

      namespace Bug_tracker.Utils
      {
        public static class Env
        {
         [ModuleInitializer]
         public static void ReadEnvFile()
         {
         if (!File.Exists("./.env")) return;

         foreach (var line in File.ReadAllLines("./.env"))
         {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line) || line.StartsWith("#")) continue;

            var parts = line.Split('=', 2);

            if (parts.Length == 2)
            {
                var name = parts[0].Trim();
                var value = parts[1].Trim();
                value = value.Substring(1, value.Length - 2);
                Console.WriteLine(name + "=" + value);
                Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable(name, value);
             };
         };

     }

  }
 }
```

Using attribute `[ModuleInitializer]` to mark a method that will run when a module is loaded

This solution fixes my problem

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You should set **ConnectionStrings** in `Program.cs`

*PotgreSQL(NpgSQL) was used here*

Add this into the `Program.cs` **(.net8)**

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppDataContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseNpgsql(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("YourConnectionName"));
});
```

Add this into the `appsettings.json`

```
 "ConnectionStrings": {
  "YourConnectionName": "Host=your_host; Port=your_port; User Id=postgres; Password=your_password; Database=your_database_name"
}
```

Add this into the your `DbContext`

```
    public class AppDataContext : DbContext
    {
        public AppDataContext(DbContextOptions<AppDataContext> options): base(options)
        { }

        ///
    }
```

Then in the **Package Manager Console:**

1. add-migration Initial
2. update-database